# Printing current date and time C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, console-application

That's an easy one, but there is an error that appears. I have to create a console application for printing current date and time.

Here is my code:

```
namespace DateTime
{
    class DateTime
    {
        public static void Main()

        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.now;
            Console.WriteLine(now);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
}
```

I'm using visual studio 2012.

Comment: There was no definition for "now"

Comment: It is [`.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) not `.now` with capital `N`. C# is case sensitive.

Comment: *Always* include the error message in the question - or the exception, if there's an exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few issues here. First, your class is called `DateTime`, which is causing the compiler to confuse it with `System.DateTime`.  Also make sure the `System` namespace is available with a `using` directive, or fully-qualifying the type. Thirdly, C# is case sensitive. It should be `Now`, not `now`. Try giving things different names:

```
using System;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(now);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You still need to fix `DateTime.now` to `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Yeah, I was in the middle of that. Done.

Answer (score 2):

A typo: `DateTime.now`. `Now` should start with the capital letter `N` as follows: `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 2):

If you getting this error:

> 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'now'

Try `DateTime.Now` with uppercase 'N' instead `DateTime.now`.

Answer (score 0):

Error   1   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DateTime\DateTime\DateTime.cs  12  30  DateTime

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)